# Impact Estimation (Number of people reached, shown in profile): Defect?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, people-reached

Only a few hours back, my profile had ~1k people reached.

Now, I've ~7k people reached. Reason??
 - I have just provided an answer to a question that already had ~6k views.

This makes me think that that estimated number shown alongside each profile is bogus. Or this there some other metrics?

Comment: After this question, my profile is showing ~40k reached.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here - this explains how that figure is reached.

Comment: I see ~40 reached (here on meta), not ~40k. And ~7k on Stack Overflow.

Comment: My mistake on 40k. But there is 7k :P

Comment: Yes, and that is due to your answer being in the top 3 answers (by rep) on that post... yeah, only 3 answers there, but that's the algo.

Comment: Shouldn't it ignore the already viewed count?

Comment: I can tell you didn't read the post I linked... the data doesn't exist in the DB. There is just a number - how many times the question has been viewed. The value is a very rough approximation.